# Looping SqlDataReader Seems to fail with only one row as a result

Tags: vb.net

I have this code

```
If (sqlDataRdr.HasRows) Then

  Do While sqlDataRdr.Read()
    outstring = outstring & Trim(sqlDataRdr.Item("a_bill_number").ToString()) & "|" & Trim(sqlDataRdr.Item("ad_old_amount").ToString()) & "|" & Trim(sqlDataRdr.Item("c_cid_name1").ToString()) & "|" & Trim(sqlDataRdr.Item("bs_prev_read_date").ToString()) & "|" & Trim(sqlDataRdr.Item("bs_read_date").ToString()) & "*"
  Loop

Else
  outstring = "No records found for the entered criteria. Please try again."
End If
```

As the title says, I get results fine as long as there are multiple rows returned, but it times out if the result is a single row. I'm sure I'm missing something silly, or doing it wrong. I'm a PHP developer being forced to write some .net so be gentle :)

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be wrong. Perhaps the problem is before this point. What is the exact error message that you receive?

Comment: I really can't see anything glaringly obviously wrong with it. Maybe try using `Do While (sqlDataRdr.Read())` instead? Clutching at straws, I know

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at the Do statement to inspect the datareader object?  If not, that would be the first step to debugging this...

Comment: When you say it times out, what specifically does the stack trace say times out (the SqlConnection or the SqlCommand and does it stop in the loop or on the SqlCommand.ExecuteReader?.  Like what Steve said, what you have here looks Ok.  If you're using this multiple times in the program don't forget to close your data reader when you're done with it as that could cause issues depending on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
If (sqlDataRdr.HasRows) Then

While sqlDataRdr.Read()
   outstring = outstring & Trim(sqlDataRdr.GetValue(sqlDataRdr.GetOrdinal("a_bill_number"))) & "|" & Trim(sqlDataRdr.GetValue(sqlDataRdr.GetOrdinal("ad_old_amount"))) & "|" & Trim(sqlDataRdr.GetValue(sqlDataRdr.GetOrdinal("c_cid_name1"))) & "|" & Trim(sqlDataRdr.GetValue(sqlDataRdr.GetOrdinal("bs_prev_read_date"))) & "|" & Trim(sqlDataRdr.GetValue(sqlDataRdr.GetOrdinal("bs_read_date"))) & "*"
end While

Else
   outstring = "No records found for the entered criteria. Please try again."
End If
```

This is a slightly different approach to retrieve data from `SqlDataReader` and it works fine even if there's only one record in it.

Comment: Are you sure this is valid code?  When I use it, I get an error saying "Loop must be preceded by a matching 'Do'".  Also, `sqlDataRdr.GetValue` returns type `Object`.  With `Option Strict On` you cannot concatenate a string with an Object.